# Centering itemize in tcolorbox automatically

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, tcolorbox

I am trying to get an `itemize` environment to center in a `tcolorbox` automatically. A manual work-around is to put it inside a `minipage` and reduce the size of the `minipage` iteratively to the size of the `itemize` environment. I have looked for a minipage alternative like `pbox` but couldn't get it to work with that (but I'm not saying this is a dead-end, I have never used `pbox` before, so maybe just did something wrong).
Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\boxwidth}{6.75cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[](NAME) at (0,0)
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        title={\textcolor{white}{\textbf{The itemize env centered}}},
        width=\boxwidth, center title, center upper, colframe = red!50!black]
        \begin{minipage}{.77\textwidth} % HERE I don't want to adjust manually!
            \begin{itemize}
                \item bla bla 
                \item blub blub blub
                \item bliblalub-blaa blaba blubb
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item blubber die blub
                    \item lore em ipsum si
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
    \end{tcolorbox}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The MWE gives the result I want, however it requires manual adjustment of the width of the `minipage`. How to get this automated? I want the `tcolorbox` size to be fixed, because I am making a tree, where several tcolorboxes are used that should all have the same size, however the content in the `itemize` environments in the boxes will not always make full use of that space, thus, I'd like it to be centered in those cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution: Wrapping the `itemize` environment in another `tcolorbox` that is centered then. The `left=...` skipping might need some adjustment however.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\boxwidth}{6.75cm}

\newtcolorbox{innerdummybox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,interior hidden,frame hidden,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,right=0pt,#1}

\begin{document}



\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  title={\textcolor{white}{\textbf{The itemize env centered}}},
  width=\boxwidth, center title, colframe = red!50!black]
  \begin{innerdummybox}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item bla bla 
    \item blub blub blub
    \item bliblalub-blaa blaba blubb
      \begin{itemize}
      \item blubber die blub
      \item lore em ipsum si
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{innerdummybox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]